# AutoExpand treeview in WPF

Tags: wpf, treeview, expand

Is there a way to automatically expand all nodes from a treeview in WPF? I searched and didn't even find an expand function in the treeview property.

Thanks

Comment: Forgot to mention I don't have TreeviewItem, but different kinds of items in my tree.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can set ItemContainerStyle and use IsExpanded property.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Grid>
      <TreeView>
         <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
               <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
         </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
         <TreeViewItem Header="Header 1">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Sub Item 1"/>
         </TreeViewItem>
         <TreeViewItem Header="Header 2">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Sub Item 2"/>
         </TreeViewItem>
      </TreeView>
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

If you need to do this from code, you can write viewmodel for your tree view items, and bind IsExpanded property to corresponding one from model. For more examples refer to great article from Josh Smith on CodeProject: [Simplifying the WPF TreeView by Using the ViewModel Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx)

Comment: I used this method for MVVM bound view and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I use:

```
private void ExpandAllNodes(TreeViewItem rootItem)
{
    foreach (object item in rootItem.Items)
    {
        TreeViewItem treeItem = (TreeViewItem)item;

        if (treeItem != null)
        {
            ExpandAllNodes(treeItem);
            treeItem.IsExpanded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In order for it to work you must call this method in a foreach loop for the root node:

```
// this loop expands all nodes
foreach (object item in myTreeView.Items)
{
    TreeViewItem treeItem = (TreeViewItem)item;

    if (treeItem != null)
    {
        ExpandAllNodes(treeItem);
        treeItem.IsExpanded = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Carlo. This will not work if you have something different from TreeViewItem in your Items collection. If you want to be sure this approach works in any case, you should use ItemContainerGenerator from your TreeView object and call it's ContainerFromItem() method.

Comment: You are right, the way I add the items to my treeview is myTree.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = myObject });, That's why it works for me. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: You can simplify the code to be myTreeView.Items.OfType<TreeViewItem>() and you will not have to check for null or case the items.

Answer (score 5):

if you want expand manually you can try

Xaml:

```
<TreeView x:Name="TreePeople">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

c#:

```
bool Expanded = false; 
// The event subscription method (for a button click)
private void ButtonExpand__Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Expanded = !Expanded;
    Style Style = new Style
    {
        TargetType = typeof(TreeViewItem)
    };

    Style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TreeViewItem.IsExpandedProperty, Expanded));
    TreePeople.ItemContainerStyle = Style;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Carlo's answer was better because it opens all levels**

This improves upon that example with a little more concise code example.

```
    private void ExpandAllNodes(TreeViewItem treeItem)
    {
        treeItem.IsExpanded = true;  
        foreach (var childItem in treeItem.Items.OfType<TreeViewItem>())
        {
                ExpandAllNodes(childItem);
        }
    }
```

**Call it by using this line of code**

```
TreeViewInstance.Items.OfType<TreeViewItem>().ToList().ForEach(ExpandAllNodes);
```

Comment: `foreach (TreeViewItem childItem in TreeItem.Items)` is shorter than your foreach but works just as fine. :)

Comment: This won't work when using MVVM because the items won't be `TreeViewItem`.  See  Anvaka's comment on Carlo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another programmatical way to manipulate full expansion of tree items, maybe via c# code, is using the `TreeViewItem.ExpandSubTree()` command on a root node.

```
private void ExpandFirstRootNode()
{
   TreeViewControl.Items[0].ExpandSubtree();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only expand 1 `Items` sub tree? Shouldn't we do all?