# Setting IsExpanded on a WPF TreeViewItem from a DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, treeviewitem

I'm trying to set the `IsExpanded` property of my `TreeView` items using a conditional template, in the `XAML`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyStatus}" Value="Opened">
    <Setter TargetName="MyTextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="True" />
</DataTrigger>
```

When I set the `MyStatus` property from the C# code, the colors are changed (so the DataTrigger works), but the nodes aren't expanded.

```
_myItems[0].MyStatus = MyStatus.Opened;
```

**How can I set the `TreeViewItem.IsExpanded` property from a `DataTrigger`?**

When I start the application, the colors are correctly set, but the green node isn't expanded:

[image: Screenshot just after starting the application]

And after changing the value of `_myItems[0].MyStatus` and `_myItems[1].MyStatus`, the colors are changed accordingly, but the green node still isn't expanded.

[image: Screenshot after clicking the Button1]

## Full Code (XAML)

The full code is a bit long, but it's 90% boilerplate.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="250">
    <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}" x:Key="MyTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <!-- ... -->
                    <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyStatus}" Value="Closed">
                        <Setter TargetName="MyTextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyStatus}" Value="Opened">
                        <Setter TargetName="MyTextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </DockPanel.Resources>

        <Button Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Button1"/>
        <TreeView Name="treeView1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

## Full Code (C#)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication6
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MyItemCollection> _myItems;

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();

            _myItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItemCollection> {
                new MyItemCollection { Name = "Parent1", MyStatus = MyStatus.Closed, SubItems = { new MyItemCollection { Name = "Child1" } } },
                new MyItemCollection { Name = "Parent2", MyStatus = MyStatus.Opened, SubItems = { new MyItemCollection { Name = "Child2" } } }
            };

            DataContext = new {
                MyItems = _myItems
            };
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            _myItems[0].MyStatus = MyStatus.Opened;
            _myItems[1].MyStatus = MyStatus.Closed;
        }
    }

    public enum MyStatus
    {
        Closed,
        Opened
    }

    public class MyItemCollection : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MyItemCollection() {
            SubItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItemCollection>();
            _myStatus = MyStatus.Closed;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<MyItemCollection> SubItems { get; set; }

        private MyStatus _myStatus;
        public MyStatus MyStatus {
            get { return _myStatus; }
            set { _myStatus = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MyStatus"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName) {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [WPF DataBound treeview expand / collapse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1717654/324969), but they use a `Style` while I use a `DataTrigger`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here. The first is that you are setting the property `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` on a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. This won't work. Instead, you're going to need to set an `ItemContainerStyle` on the `TreeView`:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <!-- put logic for handling expansion here -->
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

You can't just put the `Trigger` in here, however. Because of [`DependencyProperty` value precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx), if your user clicks on the nodes to expand or collapse them, your triggers won't be #1 on the precedence list (that is a local value). Therefore, your'e best bet is to create a new `IValueConverter` to convert from `MyStatus` to a `bool`. And then setup a `TwoWay` binding in a `Setter` in the `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" 
            Value="{Binding MyStatus, Converter={StaticResource statusToBool}}" />
</Style>
```

And your converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return ((MyStatus)value) == MyStatus.Opened;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return ((bool)value) ? MyStatus.Opened : MyStatus.Closed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using directly a boolean property `MyExpanded` in addition to the `MyStatus` enum field, to avoid the converter (the `ConvertBack` would be problematic since there are more than two values in the enum).

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something similar, and I resolved it this way:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding source}"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="{Binding Path=myStatusToBool}"
          >
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
      <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded"
              Value="False"
              />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SnapsToDevicePixels,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}}"
                     Value="True">
            <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded"
                    Value="True"
                    />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

  <TreeView.Resources>
  .....
  .....
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: <TreeView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding source}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="{Binding Path=myStatusToBool}"
            >

Answer (score 2):

I Had the same issue, but solved it without a value converter:

```
                    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```