# TreeView Expand

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm new in WPF. Let me explain you what is my case. So I have 3 TreeViews with the same source, my point is, is it possible when I expand one of the the item in the first tree automatically to expand the same element in the other trees? And I have another question how to make every line in the TreeView to be different color?

For example `1, 3, 5, 7` line to be gray, and `2,4,6,8` to be white.

```
<Grid> 
    <TreeView x:Name="TreeView1" Margin="10,20,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupsTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" IsDragDropEnabled="True"/> 
    <TreeView x:Name="TreeView2" Margin="10,20,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupsTemplate}" Grid.Column="1" IsDragDropEnabled="True"/> 
    <TreeView x:Name="TreeView3" Margin="10,20,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupsTemplate}" Grid.Column="2" IsDragDropEnabled="True"/> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: hi, welcome to stack overflow.  when asking a question include any code you have created so far. You should at least have a go and the post specific issues you are having.  There are many ways to do what you are doing.  Eg are you using the MVVM approach?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use MVVM

Comment: Do you have any code you could add above?

Comment: <Grid>                     

  <TreeView x:Name="TreeView1" Margin="10,20,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupsTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" IsDragDropEnabled="True"/>                            
 <TreeView x:Name="TreeView2" Margin="10,20,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupsTemplate}" Grid.Column="1" IsDragDropEnabled="True"/>
<TreeView x:Name="TreeView3" Margin="10,20,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupsTemplate}" Grid.Column="2" IsDragDropEnabled="True"/>
 </Grid>

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403929/setting-isexpanded-on-a-wpf-treeviewitem-from-a-datatrigger

Comment: I'd do some reading about binding TreeView - using HeirarchicalDataTemplate.  You basically need to bind IsExpanded to a value in your view model.  Once you've done that for all three treeviews you'll get the behaviour you need.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend for you as a newbie to study/try to code in [MVVM design pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx). In MVVM you can use this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295644/wpf-treeview-binding) for your requirements.

Anyway,for your current problem:

- Create a callback for 'selectionChange' event, in this event [use the name](http://www.dotnetperls.com/name) of the other treeViews to get to the controles and manipulate them.
- You can use [HierarchicalDataTemplate,styles and resurces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728671(v=vs.95).aspx) to style the treeView as you wish.