# Is it possible to set element's own property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger, expander

I am trying to set expander IsExpanded property inside DataTrigger with Setter.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <Expander x:Name="myExpander" />
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myExpander, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Value="False">
             <Setter TargetName="Self" Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
         </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
   </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The problem is when I write the code like

```
TargetName="myExpander"
```

I wanted some keyword like "self" or "." - something that associates the Setter target with its parent's elements and finds it.

Comment: You can omit TargetName. No target means self.

Comment: When i omit TargetName, then i get compile error. It says that could not find the template property 'IsExpanded'

Comment: Trigger is for one thing, while `Expander` is another. They are not in *easy-to-use* relations (it's not `Self` or `RelativeSource`). And it's totally ok to use name to reference element. What is the problem to have name?

Comment: So, after I saw this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403929/setting-isexpanded-on-a-wpf-treeviewitem-from-a-datatrigger, I realized that Triggers are not good for what you want, and you will have to use a converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Expander x:Name="myExpander" />
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger SourceName="myExpander" Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="myExpander" Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
            </Trigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Note that I used `Trigger` with `SourceName` rather than `DataTrigger` (although the latter would also work). As for the `Setter`, you need to set the `TargetName="myExpander"` in order to set the property of your expander - if you did not specify the `TargetName`, the setter would attempt to set the property on the `DataTemplate` itself.

At least that's the theoretical solution. In practice it will not work (or at least not as you expect), because a trigger based on the `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` is not a good choice for what I think you're trying to achieve. Better choice would be to subscribe to the `LostFocus` event.